# Angular add mock JSON Data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm new to angular and buildig an application that reads data from a API and renders it in an HTML table. For the moment I m trying to see how I can manipulate the table data and thereby changing the model (JSON). I understand this would need API support to make those changes, but for the moment I'd like to try this with mock data inside the Javascript.

Can you please look into this Fiddle code and tell me how I can do that ?

```
    (function() {
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

      app.controller('PeopleController', function($scope, $http) {
        $http({
          url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/584d5",
          method: "GET"
        }).success(function(data,status) {
          $scope.people = data.people;
        });
      });
    })();
```

Thanks

[Code Pen Link](http://codepen.io/silican/pen/JXEvJY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you'd like to change the JSON? you can try a PUT.

Here's your codepen modified: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZRYxZ?editors=1010

```
$scope.myData = {"people":[{"personName":"Scott Walker","personAge":"43","dateOfBirth":"09-12-1972","location":"Leeds","gender":"male"},{"personName":"Paula Lamb","personAge":"38","dateOfBirth":"02-01-1978","location":"Alberta","gender":"female"},{"personName":"Jonathan Joestar","personAge":"22","dateOfBirth":"02-28-1850","location":"UK","gender":"male"}]};

$http.put('https://api.myjson.com/bins/584d5', $scope.myData)
    .success(function (data) {
    // alert("success!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a plunker for you. Basically you can just call the http request to the place where the json file is located. So in this case it is just root, but if it is in a map, just follow the path relative from index.

```
$http({
  url: "example.json",
  method: "GET"
}).success(function(data, status) {
  console.log($scope.people);
  $scope.people = data.people;
});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/LmoRco8FN4Ck8xZ7bM2x